# Mongoose: populate an array based on ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a small CRUD application, where user is authenticated and able to create/add to favorites some recipes. I have been stuck on the adding to favorites for some time now.

This is my user schema:

```
const UserSchema = Schema({
    googleId: String,
    name: String,
    favorites: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe' }],
});
```

And this is my recipe schema:

```
const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Title of the recipe is required'],
    },
    category: {
        type: Array,
        required: [true, 'Category is required'],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Description is required'],
    },
    imgUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Image is required'],
    },
    ingredients: {
        type: Array,
        required: [true, 'Ingredients are required'],
    },
    timeOfPreparation: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    preparation: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    sourceName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    sourceUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    fans: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});
```

Both are exported in this manner from their respective files:

```
    const Recipe = mongoose.model('recipe', RecipeSchema);
    const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

    module.exports = Recipe;   
    module.exports = User;
```

The user is authenticated with passport and this part works just fine. Then, when a user clicks favorite button on the front end (or I send a request in postman) to endpoint (PUT) '/:userId/favorites', the controller then goes to the array of favorites and pushes a new id:

```
exports.add_to_favorite = (req, res) => {
        const { recipeId } = req.body;

            User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                {
                    _id: req.params.userId,
                },
                { $addToSet: { favorites: recipeId } }
            ).then(() => {
                User.findById({
                    _id: req.params.userId,
                }).then(() => res.send(res.status));
            });
        };
```

However, as I would like to show favorites on frontend, not only their ids, I found a way to connect those two collections: populate method in mongoose. This however has not worked as anticipated and I get undefined:

```
exports.get_favorites = (req, res) => {
    User.findById({
        _id: req.params.userId,
    })
        .populate('favorites')
        .exec((err, recipe) => {
            console.log(recipe);
            res.send(recipe);
        });
};
```

How should I populate the favorites array with actual objects that contain data needed for me to render in then on my front end part of application?

Comment: Two things.. What is it currently returning when you populate favorites, and what does it return if you don't explicitly populate favorites

Comment: Currently it returns undefined. If I don't populate them but just return data from database it's actually an array of IDs, if that's what you meant

Comment: See my solution.. I think solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is gonna sound pretty silly, but I think the issue is that you export you recipe model with a lower case r, `recipe`, but reference it with an upper case R, `Recipe`. If you make those consistent, I think it will work..

**Note**: I think the same thing will need to be done with your reference to the `user` model inside the `recipe` model

Comment: Indeed, silly I was :) Thank you so much for pointing it out!